# How to access attributes in another tkinter frame subclass?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.8

I'm trying to access `self.var_1` in `frame_2` and `self.var_2` in `frame_1`?

Here is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.frame_1 = Frame1(self)
        self.frame_1.pack()
        self.frame_2 = Frame2(self)
        self.frame_2.pack()


class Frame1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.var_1 = 'Variable_1'


class Frame2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.var_2 = 'Variable_2'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

I tried this.

```
class Frame2(tk.Frame):
    
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            super().__init__(master)
            self.var_2 = 'Variable_2'
            self.var_1 = self.master.frame_1.var_1
```

But it is not gonna work for `Frame1` because `self.master.frame_2.var_2` is undefined.

```
class Frame1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.var_1 = 'Variable_1'
        self.var_2 = self.master.frame_2.var_2
```

Comment: create a method that will set those values then call it in the main class after initiating both of those classes

Comment: I didn't understand it until I figured out by myself! Anyway, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the instance of `Root` as master when creating instances of `Frame1` and `Frame2`, and because the instance of `Root` has references to the frames, one way is to save a reference to `master`:

```
class Frame1(tk.Frame):   
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.root = master
        self.var_1 = 'Variable_1'
```

With that, you can use `self.root.frame_1.var_1` and `self.root.frame_2.var_2` within both `Frame1` and `Frame2`.

Another solution might be to add a method to `Root` which returns one or both frames. For example, you could define `get_frames` like so:

```
class Root:
    ...
    def get_frames(self):
        return self.frame_1, self.frame_2
```

You can then call this method to get the frames, and then use the frame to get the variable:

```
frame1, frame2 = self.root.get_frames()
print(frame1.var_1)
```

It's hard to say which solution is best based on this simple example. Regardless, this isn't a tkinter problem, it's just a fundamental aspect of object-oriented programming: to access an attribute of an object you need a reference to the object. You can either have a caller pass it in, or you can fetch it when you need it.

Comment: I think it does `self.master = master` automatically even though I did it both ways, but it still gives an error . And just by doing `Frame1(self)` again it will work but sometime it duplicates itself in tkinter, which is expected .

Comment: @RozhyarGaylan: you are right. I don't use "master" myself and forget that tkinter does that. I've changed the name of that variable in my answer.

Comment: @RozhyarGaylan: you of course can't reference the variable in the other class before the other class has been instantiated.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with threading or multiprocessing?

Comment: @RozhyarGaylan: no, that won't help  you access something that doesn't exist. What do you expect to accomplish when trying to reference something that hasn't been created yet?

Comment: Actually I knew how to do it. But I needed a general solution.

Comment: And you were right, it wouldn't work the way I did 